# Please help me identify unknown bag of lego

Tags: set-identification

I got a bag of LEGO bricks at our local share shed with the number 4 on it. A QR-code on the bag encodes the number 6172089. The bag says 2017.
Pieces are all khaki tones, tan, beige, sage green, brown. There is a large circular time piece and what looks like gear pieces.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to upload a picture? Are you sure you don't want to use the [search](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/search?q=6172089)?

Comment: Hi Katy and welcome to Bricks.SE! As you can see, we already feature a guide on identifying sets based on sealed bags. Please give that process a try and let us know if you have any issues while doing so. We'd love to hear your feedback and could help both you and anybody else with the same problem later on.